# Deciding winner in an optimally played 2-player game

Tags: algorithm, recursion, game-theory, minmax

I came across [this question](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/47870?locale=en). According to the question:

> ‘samu’ and ‘vibhu’ are playing a game where there are N integers from 1 to N lying on the table. In each turn, the player gets to pick one integer to mark as visited from among the previously unvisited ones. If in a turn, the player picks a number which completes the picking of three consecutive numbers, he wins. i.e., say at some stage in the game 2 and 4 are already picked(visited) if the player now picks 3, he wins. Assuming samu starts first and both the players play perfectly optimally, who is the winner.

I tried to apply the WL algorithm (after understanding it properly)[described here](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/algorithm-games/) which is:

```
boolean isWinning(position pos) {
    moves[] = possible positions to which I can move from the position pos;
    for (all x in moves) 
        if (!isWinning(x)) return true;
    return false; 
}
```

So, my code is(after suitably modifying the WL algorithm):

```
public class HelloWorld{

    public static boolean[] visited;
    public static int n;
    public static void main(String []args){

        n=12;
        visited=new boolean[n];
        java.util.Arrays.fill(visited,false);
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            visited[i]=true;
            if(isWinning(i)){
                System.out.println("first one wins");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            visited[i]=false;
        }
        System.out.println("second one wins");
    }

    public static boolean isWinning(int x){
        if(threeStrikes()){
            return true;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            if(!visited[i]){
                visited[i]=true;
                if(!isWinning(i)){
                    return true;
                }
                visited[i]=false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public static boolean threeStrikes(){
        for(int i=0; i<n-2; i++){
            if(visited[i]&&visited[i+1]&&visited[i+2]){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem is that it prints "first one wins" for n=6. In [this discussion](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/47870?locale=en) thread, the op has said that for n=6, the second one should win. I don't know if he is wrong or if my code is missing something. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, here is a revised version of your code:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static boolean[] visited;
    public static int n;
    public static void main(String []args){

        n=12;
        visited=new boolean[n];
        java.util.Arrays.fill(visited,false);
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            visited[i]=true;
            if(!isOpponentWinning()){
                System.out.println("first one wins");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            visited[i]=false;
        }
        System.out.println("second one wins");
    }

    public static boolean isOpponentWinning(){
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            if(!visited[i]){
                visited[i]=true;
                if(threeStrikes() || !isOpponentWinning()){
                    visited[i]=false;
                    return true;
                }
                visited[i]=false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public static boolean threeStrikes(){
        for(int i=0; i<n-2; i++){
            if(visited[i]&&visited[i+1]&&visited[i+2]){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The modifications were:

1. *isWinning()* is actually checking if the opponent of the current player is winning so I changed it to *isOpponentWinning()* just for clarity.
2. Returning *true* when the opponent has *threeStrikes()* is wrong, since it was negated by the caller (who is the winning player). So the stopping criterion is now true when the last player reached a three-strike, and thus returning true **here** is correct.
3. Since we're checking if the opponent is winning (and not the current player), negation should be added also in the first call to *isOpponentWinning()* (in the main function).
4. For correct backtracking, I added `visited[i]=false` before returning `true` in `isOpponentWinning()`.

About your question regarding n=6, indeed **the second one should win**.
Say player *A* plays first and *B* plays second.

- If *A* chooses 1, *B* can choose 4 and then whatever *A* chooses next *B* can win in it's next turn.
- If *A* chooses 2, *B* can choose 5 and then whatever *A* chooses next *B* can win in it's next turn.
- If *A* chooses 3, *B* can choose 6 and then whatever *A* chooses next *B* can win in it's next turn.

The rest of the options are symmetrical.
We get that whatever *A* chooses as it's first move, *B* can guarantee a win.